# pre populated edit text crashes app android android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm making a fun little Facebook clone for a project and I've ran into a problem. I am trying to make an edit profile page. to do this I am pre-populating the edit texts with user data I get from my web server using retrofit/gson and using the `setText()` in order to fit the user data into where it is supposed to be.

it crashes when I edit the edit text I pre-populate

how I get the data from the server

```
val response = retrofit.getprofile(dataset)
            try {
                val userName = response.body()?.profileModel?.name
                val city = response.body()?.profileModel?.city
                val country = response.body()?.profileModel?.country
                val bio = response.body()?.profileModel?.bio
                val friends = response.body()?.profileModel?.friends


                mainfunc(userName,city,country,bio,friends)}
```

mainfunc:

```
    private fun mainfunc(userName: String?, city: String?, country: String?, bio: String?, friends: String?) {
    println(userName)
    println(city)
    println(country)
    println(bio)
    println(friends)


    try {
        view?.bio_txt?.setText(bio)

    }catch (e: Exception){
        println(e)
    }

}
```

my XML:

```
    <EditText
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/bio_txt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/midline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vguideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vguideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />
```

right now I am just trying to get bio to work, the rest should be easy after this one.

I read some stuff on stack overflow about the edit text id being wrong, or to use findview by id.

In my case I cannot use findviewbyid because I am doing all of this within a fragment. as for the id being wrong the id is just not wrong, when I control-click on bio_txt in mainfunc it takes me right where its supposed to in the XML.

the weird thing about this is that it seems to go away when it wants to. someone I live with came to see me and I explained to them what was going on. when I went to go demonstrate the app crashing it didn't crash. I had left the app open on the editing screen  that i was having issues with while I explained my code for 5ish minutes.

here is the full error log

```
2022-08-29 03:04:58.305 25019-25019/com.basicbook E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
2022-08-29 03:04:58.306 25019-25019/com.basicbook E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2022-08-29 03:04:58.309 25019-25019/com.basicbook E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.text.method.WordIterator.setCharSequence(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.parse(SpellChecker.java:563)
        at android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.parse(SpellChecker.java:520)
        at android.widget.SpellChecker.spellCheck(SpellChecker.java:260)
        at android.widget.Editor.updateSpellCheckSpans(Editor.java:927)
        at android.widget.Editor.sendOnTextChanged(Editor.java:1522)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10585)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:10688)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:13538)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1267)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:576)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:315)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:507)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:305)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:49)
        at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:228)
        at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:141)
        at androidx.emoji2.viewsintegration.EmojiKeyListener.onKeyDown(EmojiKeyListener.java:58)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:8470)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:8227)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2842)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:14153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:476)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4082)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:124)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:86)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:142)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:601)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3106)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:390)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5911)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5274)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5331)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5297)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5305)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5506)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5278)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5331)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5297)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5305)
        at android.view.ViewRootIm
2022-08-29 03:04:58.309 25019-25019/com.basicbook D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-08-29 03:04:58.312 25019-25019/com.basicbook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.basicbook, PID: 25019
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.text.method.WordIterator.setCharSequence(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.parse(SpellChecker.java:563)
        at android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.parse(SpellChecker.java:520)
        at android.widget.SpellChecker.spellCheck(SpellChecker.java:260)
        at android.widget.Editor.updateSpellCheckSpans(Editor.java:927)
        at android.widget.Editor.sendOnTextChanged(Editor.java:1522)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10585)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:10688)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:13538)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1267)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:576)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:315)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:507)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:305)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:49)
        at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:228)
        at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:141)
        at androidx.emoji2.viewsintegration.EmojiKeyListener.onKeyDown(EmojiKeyListener.java:58)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:8470)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:8227)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2842)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:14153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1948)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:476)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4082)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:124)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:86)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:142)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:601)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3106)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:390)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5911)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5274)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5331)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5297)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5305)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5506)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5278)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5331)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5297)
2022-08-29 03:04:58.313 25019-25019/com.basicbook E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5305)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5278)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5331)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5297)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5482)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5640)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3091)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2633)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2624)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3068)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:143)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7476)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:939)
2022-08-29 03:04:58.348 25019-25019/com.basicbook I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25019 SIG: 9
```

Comment: show me how you are getting the EditText id inside the fragment

Comment: `view?.bio_txt?.setText(bio)` is how I am getting the EditText id from the fragment, `view` is a `val` that I set with the following: `val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)` . I have done similar things with safe args

Comment: I can't tell what is causing this issue without watching the all the classes. This can happen when you have two layouts for portrait and landscape mode. Anyway what you are doing is not considered as best practice. Try viewBinding, you will not have these null exceptions when you use viewBinding.